# How to add general keyword to <select>

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I got a dropdown list like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="afrapporteringsTidDropdown" data-bind="options:moedeDetaljer.afrapportering"></select>
            </div>
```

This is all good, and works well with the databinding done using KnockoutJS.

However, my moedeDetaljer.afrapportering is a list containing the following:

```
afrapportering: ["0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30"]
```

My question is: What is the most elegant way of making the dropdown list show "0 minutes", "5 minutes" and so on? So basically, how to add the minutes after the stored number in the list?

Comment: new string array, for loop? won't it work?

Comment: Yeah it will, but I was looking for a more elegant solution than that, if there is such :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`optionsText` parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-4-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-with-displayed-text-computed-as-a-function-of-the-represented-item) of the `options` binding can take a function where you can format the display text as you like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="afrapporteringsTidDropdown" 
   data-bind="options: afrapportering, 
              optionsText: function(item) { return item + ' minutes' }">
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8tgd90v/).